# Retrieve ascendant rows of a hierarchy

Tags: sql, oracle, connect-by

I have a sample table that contains 3 columns: `id`, `parent_id` and `name`

Let's say that the hierarchy that is present in my table is as follows:

```
I
  I.A
    I.A.a
    I.A.b
      I.A.b1
      I.A.b2
  I.B
  I.C
II
  II.A
```

My goal is to retrieve all the ascendants of a given row. For example, for `I.A.b2`, the result would be:

```
I
I.A
I.A.b
I.A.b2
```

I tried to use the following `connect-by` query but with no success:

```
 SELECT name
 FROM test 
 where id = 7 -- 7 is the id of I.A.b2 in my example
 CONNECT BY PRIOR id = parent_id
 START WITH parent_id is null;
```

Any suggestion would be helpful

Comment: I'm assuming this is Oracle. Please tag it as such to help folks find this question that follow that tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to go through the records in the opposite order (start at the end) and then reverse the order with an `order by` as follows:

```
SELECT     name
FROM       test 
CONNECT BY PRIOR parent_id = id
START WITH id = 7
ORDER BY   rownum DESC
```

To get the level of each record in the tree, you could use the `row_number()` analytic function:

```
SELECT     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY rownum DESC), name
FROM       test 
CONNECT BY PRIOR parent_id = id
START WITH id = 7
ORDER BY   rownum DESC
```

Comment: The query works perfectly, but I have an additional feature  to retrieve the level of the hierarchy. Reversing the order causes also the level to be reversed. Is there a way to get the original level? Thanks

Comment: See addition to my answer.